# Set var as attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that gives each div its own data-page-index attribute as a number, I have variables that pull specific data-page-index values and convert them to integers for some calculations, but i need to re-apply this number using its var name, for example,

```
var foo =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index')),
    next = (foo+1)
    nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="'' +next+ '"]')
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Your issue was a small syntax mistake. You had an extra single quote in there.

```
nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="'' +next+ '"]')
/* -----------------------------^---------- */
```

It is possible to see here on Stack Overflow thanks to the syntax highlighting that there is a problem. Your IDE should have also had the same effect.

The correct code should look something like this ( I don't really like defining multiple variables on one line so I've split them up -

```
var foo =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index'));
var next = foo+1;
var nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="' + next + '"]');
```

<s>I could be wrong... but I think that `next` is a preserved keyword. This might be causing you some unpredictable issues... I recommend changing the name of that variable as well...</s> [Irrelevant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Comment: Doesn't he need a comma after next=(foo+1) as well?

Comment: @mat - you are correct... But I'm not a big fan of that syntax, so I've changed it.

Comment: Agreed. I hate when people try to get all fancy with the vars.

Comment: @lix and there should also be a semi-colon after the last var, i just ommited them by mistake in this example. I always seperate my vars with commas and have them on one line, is it just personal preference or will i run into issues eventually?

Comment: @tim - The issues you might run into are people on [so] telling you that they don't like that convention :-P

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely :

```
var foo =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index')),
next = (foo+1) // <---parse this one too
nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="'' +next+ '"]')
   //---------------------------^--------------you have extra (') here
```

It should be :

```
var foo =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index')),
next = parseInt(foo+1);
nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="' +next+ '"]');
```

Comment: +1 for actually indicating where the problem was. Sometimes, when you have been staring at a piece of code for a long time, it's easy to miss little errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var foo =  parseInt(active.data('page-index')),
next = (foo + 1)
nextfoo = $('[data-page-index="' + next + '"]')
```

You had an erroneous double `''` in the attribute selector.